# What's the best way to run a function after a request sent by a server?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, websocket, push-notification, server-sent-events

Here is the use case:

- the user launches the app and grants permission, the app connects to the server
- at some point in the future, the server sends a request to the app
  the app
- regardless of whether it is running or not in the foreground or background, wakes up to run this code
  Here are some options I have explored which I am unsure about:
- server sent events
- websockets
- push notifications

Is there a reliable and safe way to do this on android, whether it's Kotlin or Flutter? Can you provide examples or documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the best way to do it is with push notifications!

Websockets and server sent events are better suited for other use cases. Persistent connections to a server are resource consuming, and both Android and iOS have mechanisms in place to terminate apps running in the background to save memory etc. So we would probably lose the connection and not be able to receive anything from the server if we minimized the app or locked our phone screen.

Push notifications are basically built for this exact use case because, even though they work differently on Android and iOS, they are built to receive messages from a server regardless of whether the app is in the foreground, background, or not even currently running.

I used Firebase Cloud Messaging to build my app since it's primarily an Android app. It worked like a charm.